# if $H^{n+1}(G,A)=0$ for all $G$-module $A$ ,then $H^{k}(G,A)=0$ for all $k>n$ and for all $G$-modules $A$.

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

if $H^{n+1}(G,A)=0$ for all $G$-module $A$ ,then $H^{k}(G,A)=0$ for all $k>n$ and for all $G$-modules $A$.

any hint or idea or references to study will be great,thanks.

Comment: Hint:embed $A$ into an injective $I$, and use the long exact sequence associated to $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow I\rightarrow A'\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @user113969 ,can you explain what is $A^{'}$?,is it derivation of $A$? can you explain a little more?thanks.

Comment: No, $A'$ is just the quotient $I/A$. Because $I$ is injective, it has vanishing cohomology. The long exact sequence give then $H^i(G,A')=H^{i+1}(G,A)$ for $i>0$. Can you conclude from there ?

Comment: should I use (for all $G$-modules, from $\frac{I}{A}$ ,$H^{n+1}(G,\frac{I}{A})=0$)?is it right?thanks.

Comment: Yes, and you conclude that for all $G$-module, $H^{n+2}(G,A)=0$, and so on